# Perfomance impact when using lexicographically ordered string for primary key

Tags: database, postgresql, database-indexes

How much performance hit is when using string primary key in PostgreSQL (or generally in any whell-known DBMS)?
String is lexicographically ordered on its first half (as string date) and random in another, ex.: `20231201_A32vhfe`

More info:

- Only equality `=` conditions will be used (no range searches with `LIKE`)
- Reads are much more often than inserts
- Key will have 15-30 length (non constant length)
- Table will have ~10M records

Optimization goal is for read, write doesn't matter because quite rare.

Thank you!

PS: as additional question (but not mandatory to choose as answer) what would be write performance impact if:

- Inserts will be with keys that uses present time in first part of the string - so inserts are generally ordered by date but not ordered inside specific day frame
- Deletes as frequent as inserts but deletes are from arbitrary position

Comment: SQL is unordered , so the string layout really does not matter when it comes to the inserts.

Comment: It doesn't for inserts, but does for index choice and construction, and therefore for lookup performance (select, update, delete, conflicting inserts).

Comment: 10 million records is not a lot, don't worry too much. For the rest, just measure. Ps. "not mandatary" is kind of strange, not a single question on SO is mandatory for anyone.

Comment: For fixed-length 15-character keys, you could instead make it a proper `timestamp`. The date part remains as it was but gets the added benefit of being directly usable as date, while the time part can accommodate almost 9e10 different random values (microsecond resolution). 6 ASCII alphanumerics can store around 6e10 values, so this would also give your random values more sparsity and make them harder to brute-force through. This begins to crumble past the 15

Comment: *How much performance hit ...*. The **only** way for you to know is to test it on your system/hardware. Build a table with the proposed key and another with an additional integer key, populate each (3M-4M rows should be sufficient). Then run your queries capturing performance statistics. Analyze those results.

Comment: @Zegarek although it is not the case when second part of the string encodes something, it is however generally a good idea, do you mean `timestamp(6)` for microsecond resolution?

Comment: @Arkemlar just `timestamp` will suffice, without a range/precision spec. It can always hold timestamps down to a microsecond: [*If no precision is specified in a constant specification, it defaults to the precision of the literal value (but not more than 6 digits).*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

It will be a tad slower than an integer, but I doubt that you will notice the difference. Run a benchmark if you want certainty.

You should definitely define the column with `COLLATE "C"` so that you don't have any overhead from natural language collations.

Comment: The tip about collation is nice!